# Issue with schedule module timing

Tags: python, scheduler

In python 3.9.0

```
schedule.every().minute.at(":58").do(function_1)
```

Instead of calling function at every single minute, It works only on alternate minutes skipping the next minute...

```
time 12:00 it works
time 12:01 it miss ( it is supposed to work)
time 12:02 it works
time 12:03 it miss
time 12:04 it works.
```

and so on...

Could you please suggest a fix?

Comment: How long does `function_1` take to execute?

Comment: one second to maximum 8 seconds.